# HTML5: Is iPhone4's hardware acceleration that much weaker than compared to the 4s?

Tags: html, css, iphone-4, hardware-acceleration

I created a HTML5 web application that uses hardware acceleration via CSS3 property `translateZ(0)`.

On my 4s every works really very smooth.

When I test the same thing on a iPhone4, then performance goes down extremely. Almost unusable.

Is there some kind of freaky trick to enable hardware acceleration for the iPhone4? Or is its GPU simply that weak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came out that I've been doing hardware-accelerated transitions the wrong way, see:

[What are the "golden rules" to increase CSS3 transition performance on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277206/what-are-the-golden-rules-to-increase-css3-transition-performance-on-mobile-de)

Using `translate3d(x, y, z)` instead of `translateZ(0)` with `left:x` did the trick for me. Now even on older iPhones all transitions run very smoothly.